# How much is the reward for Stag Party?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

At the end of the mission, you're given the option to either turn Josh Birk in to Cyrus to get a bonus to City Takeovers, or you can give him to Shaundi to turn him into a Homie. Cyrus mentioned that they'd put pressure on Morningstar instead of the Saints, so I assume the bonus is within their territory.

I decided to make Josh my Homie, but I was wondering how much the bonus was for the City Takeover? What area of the city is it in? It it always the same area every time, or will it change based on whether you've taken over that area of the city or not?

I've taken over a fair bit of Morningstar territory, which is partially why I didn't go for this reward. I didn't want it to go to waste if it gave me areas which I'd already taken over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Choosing to give Josh over to Cyrus results in you receiving a "City Takeover" bonus, separate from the City Takeover upgrade. Choosing this bonus will not lock out the regular City Takeover upgrade.

Using this bonus allows you to take control of one large area of the city *of your choice*. This area is outlined by a **bold purple line**, includes more than just a single Diversion/Property, and is named, like Loren Square or Sunset Park (basically, the neighborhood division lines).

It does *not* have to be within Morningstar territory. Taking control of the area will automatically complete all Diversions in the area, as well as automatically give you all properties in the area.

Answer (score 2):

Using City Takeover on a district will give you credit for having finished all the activities, bought all the available buildings, and everything else that counts towards the City Takeover percentage.  Achievements, percentages, activity completion etc, are all tracked as if you'd gone and done it "the hard way."

The exception to this is there are certain cribs that you can only earn by playing the relevant storyline mission.  I don't believe it's possible to get 100% in a district that contains one of these cribs until you've unlocked it.