# What does the STAG City Takeover allow me to do?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much is the reward for Stag Party?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37462/how-much-is-the-reward-for-stag-party)

I just finished the STAG party mission in Saints Row 3, and gave Birk to Cyrus so now I have a STAG city takeover option.

If I use this, will it just class the neighbourhood as 100%, but will I still need to buy the shops/complete the diversions etc?

If not, then will they count in my stats/100% - i.e. will I end up only having bought 45/56 locations for example?